# Hide Managed Custom Object Field

Tags: managed-package, custom-object

We want to delete a managed package field or change its data type but its not possible. A workaround is we can hide it from page layout so package user can see it. We have tried this to but it is not working. Here are the step we followed :

> Setup >> Create >> Objects >> Object we want to change >> Page Layout >> remove the field from layout

The package user add our custom object to Lead page layout.

Steps :

> Setup >> Lead Layout >> Related Lists >> Drag and drop manage custom
>   object

So what are we doing wrong field accessibility is also showing field hidden attaching screen shot.[image]

So can anyone guide us what are we doing wrong?

Comment: check for any other record type for which it may be accessble.

Comment: Every record type is behaving the same way.

Comment: Are there any permission sets that might be granting field accessibility?

Comment: No we have not added any permission set